# How to create Elastic beanstalk configuration template for a Environment

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Whenever i create a new Environment in Elastic Beanstalk, i manually configure the Custom AMI ID, SNS notifications etc., but i want to do it automatically i.e, save the settings(custom AMI ID, SNS, key-pair etc.,) into a configuration template. Is it through Command line tools or from AWS management console that we can create this Configuration Template. Please suggest me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elastic Beanstalk's console is pretty lacking when it comes to configuring templates. You can't update or delete templates. There is a [command line tool](http://aws.amazon.com/code/6752709412171743) for full control.

You can also get the [AWS Eclipse plugin](http://aws.amazon.com/eclipse/). It's not as full featured like the CLI, but much better than web console.

Answer (score 8):

You can easily do this through Amazon's web console. If you have a configuration you like just press save configuration. You can then use edit/load configuration to push that to new environments

[image: Web Console]

If you are using the elastic beanstalk command line tools, when you setup an environment using the command *git aws.config* it creates a directory called *.elasticbeanstalk* with a file in it called *config* that looks like this:

```
[global]
AwsCredentialFile=/path/to/file/with/aws/account/credentials
ApplicationName=YourAppName
DevToolsEndpoint=git.elasticbeanstalk.your-region-name.amazonaws.com
EnvironmentName=yourEnvName
Region=your-region-name
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This config file description is just what I needed for setting up pushing to an existing Elastic Beanstalk.